Making a ROS Node for a Semantic Segmentation Model I have devleoped
I have developed a SemSeg model using UNET. I want to implement it in my stack. I have converted the model to an ONNX version. I want to run it using a NVIDIA ORIN Device. What are the steps involved in making a ros node for this model? Any tutorials/links/concepts I should go through? THis is ROS HUMBLE by the way!
